# Why does PostgreSQL aggregate result in the Index or Seq scan outputting all columns of the table?

Tags: postgresql

Doing a query like this:

```
SELECT fruit, avg(cost) FROM fruit_table GROUP BY fruit
```

results in a query plan like this:

```
Sort  (cost=3713873.41..3713874.46 rows=420 width=16)
  Output: fruit, (avg(cost))
  Sort Key: fruittable.fruit
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3713849.87..3713855.12 rows=420 width=16)
      Output: fruit, (avg(cost))
      ->  Seq Scan on public.fruit  (cost=0.00..3677849.91 rows=7199991 width=16)
          Output: fruit, weight, cost, ...
```

The result is correct, but ideally, for performance reasons I would like to have weight omitted in the output of index/seq scan - what am I doing wrong?

This is the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE:

```
Sort  (cost=3713873.41..3713874.46 rows=420 width=16) (actual time=31156.940..31156.958 rows=612 loops=1)
  Output: fruit, (avg(cost))
  Sort Key: fruittable.fruit
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 53kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3713849.87..3713855.12 rows=420 width=16) (actual time=31156.272..31156.729 rows=612 loops=1)
    Output: fruit, avg(cost)
    ->  Seq Scan on public.fruittable  (cost=0.00..3677849.91 rows=7199991 width=16) (actual time=0.004..15050.636 rows=7199991 loops=1)
      Output: fruit, weight, cost, ...
Total runtime: 31157.097 ms
```

### 1. EDIT

I run the following queries based on Craig's comment:

```
SELECT
pg_stat_get_live_tuples('fruittable'::regclass), 
pg_stat_get_dead_tuples('fruittable'::regclass), 
pg_relation_size('fruittable'::regclass), 
pg_total_relation_size('fruittable'::regclass); 

-- OUTPUT:
pg_stat_get_live_tuples: 0 
pg_stat_get_dead_tuples: 0 
pg_relation_size: 29539123200 
pg_total_relation_size: 32118743040
```

and

```
SELECT avg(pg_column_size(x)) FROM (SELECT * FROM fruittable LIMIT 1000) AS x;

-- OUTPUT
avg: 1354.68
```

### 2. EDIT

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE x_2009
(
  c_a character varying(70),
  c_b character varying(70),
  c_c character varying(70),
  c_d character varying(70),
  c_e character varying(70),
  c_f double precision,
  v_g character varying(70),
  v_h character varying(70),
  c_i double precision,
  c_j double precision,
  d_k character varying(70),
  d_l character varying(70),
  c_m character varying(70),
  c_n character varying(70),
  d_o character varying(70),
  d_p character varying(70),
  d_q character varying(70),
  v_r character varying(70),
  c_s character varying(70),
  v_t double precision,
  v_u double precision,
  c_v character varying(70),
  v_w double precision,
  v_x double precision,
  v_y double precision,
  v_z double precision,
  c_aa double precision,
  v_ab double precision,
  v_ac double precision,
  v_ad double precision,
  v_ae double precision,
  v_af double precision,
  v_ag double precision,
  v_ah double precision,
  v_ai double precision,
  v_aj double precision,
  v_ak double precision,
  v_al double precision,
  v_am double precision,
  v_an double precision,
  v_ao double precision,
  v_ap double precision,
  v_aq double precision,
  v_ar double precision,
  v_as double precision,
  v_at double precision,
  v_au double precision,
  v_av double precision,
  v_aw double precision,
  v_ax double precision,
  v_ay double precision,
  v_az_cost double precision,
  v_ba double precision,
  v_bb double precision,
  v_bc double precision,
  v_bd double precision,
  v_be double precision,
  v_bf double precision,
  v_bg double precision,
  v_bh double precision,
  v_bi double precision,
  v_bj double precision,
  v_bk double precision,
  v_bl double precision,
  v_bm double precision,
  v_bn double precision,
  v_bo double precision,
  v_bp double precision,
  v_bq double precision,
  v_br double precision,
  v_bs double precision,
  v_bt double precision,
  v_bu double precision,
  v_bv double precision,
  v_bw double precision,
  v_bx double precision,
  v_by double precision,
  v_bz double precision,
  v_ca double precision,
  v_cb double precision,
  v_cc double precision,
  v_cd double precision,
  v_ce double precision,
  v_cf double precision,
  v_cg double precision,
  v_ch double precision,
  v_ci double precision,
  v_cj double precision,
  v_ck double precision,
  v_cl double precision,
  v_cm double precision,
  v_cn double precision,
  v_co double precision,
  v_cp double precision,
  v_cq double precision,
  v_cr double precision,
  v_cs double precision,
  v_ct double precision,
  v_cu double precision,
  v_cv double precision,
  v_cw double precision,
  v_cx double precision,
  v_cy double precision,
  v_cz double precision,
  v_da double precision,
  v_db double precision,
  v_dc double precision,
  v_dd double precision,
  v_de double precision,
  v_df double precision,
  v_dg double precision,
  v_dh double precision,
  v_di double precision,
  v_dj double precision,
  v_dk double precision,
  v_dl double precision,
  c_dm character varying(70),
  c_dn double precision,
  v_do double precision,
  v_dp double precision,
  v_dq double precision,
  v_dr double precision,
  v_ds double precision,
  v_dt double precision,
  v_du double precision,
  v_dv double precision,
  v_dw double precision,
  v_dx double precision,
  v_dy double precision,
  v_dz double precision,
  v_ea double precision,
  v_eb double precision,
  v_ec double precision,
  v_ed double precision,
  v_ee double precision,
  v_ef double precision,
  v_eg double precision,
  v_eh double precision,
  v_ei double precision,
  v_ej double precision,
  v_ek double precision,
  v_el double precision,
  v_em double precision,
  v_en double precision,
  v_eo double precision,
  v_ep double precision,
  v_eq double precision,
  v_er double precision,
  v_es double precision,
  v_et double precision,
  v_eu double precision,
  v_ev double precision,
  v_ew double precision,
  v_ex character varying(70),
  c_ey character varying(70),
  c_ez character varying(70),
  c_fa character varying(70),
  c_fb character varying(70),
  d_fc character varying(70),
  v_fd character varying(70),
  v_fe double precision,
  v_ff double precision,
  v_fg double precision,
  v_fh double precision,
  v_fi double precision,
  v_fj double precision,
  c_fk double precision,
  c_fl character varying(70),
  v_fm character varying(70)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE x_2009
  OWNER TO xxx;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE x_2009 TO xxx;

-- Index: x_2009_idx_c_a

CREATE INDEX x_2009_idx_c_a
  ON x_2009
  USING btree
  (c_a);

-- Index: x_2009_idx_c_a_and_v_g

CREATE INDEX x_2009_idx_c_a_and_v_g
  ON x_2009
  USING btree
  (v_g, c_a);

-- Index: x_2009_idx_v_g

CREATE INDEX x_2009_idx_v_g
  ON x_2009
  USING btree
  (v_g);
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that the query plan do not fit the query (see `Limit`).  Who's who then?

Comment: Correct. I have adjusted the code sections - the problem of course remains the same

Comment: Could you replace the current plan with that of an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`?  And which PG version do you use?

Comment: Well, it's no big surprise that a sequential scan touches all columns of all record of your table - this is how it is supposed to work.  The strange is that the seqscan takes so much time.  Do you have lots of updates and inserts on this table?  If yes, do you regularly vacuum (or better, autovacuum) it?

Comment: It's doing a sequential scan not an index scan. Here 'output' just shows that it can access all columns. There's no real advantage to skipping them, as whole blocks are read anyway. If you could somehow make it ignore "weight" your query would not get any faster.

Comment: Please run http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat

Comment: Please run: `SELECT pg_stat_get_live_tuples('fruittable'::regclass), pg_stat_get_dead_tuples('fruittable'::regclass), pg_relation_size('fruittable'::regclass),  pg_total_relation_size('fruittable'::regclass);` and `SELECT avg(pg_column_size(x)) FROM (SELECT * FROM fruittable LIMIT 1000) AS x`;

Comment: ... or instead `CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple` and `SELECT * FROM pgstattuple('fruittable');` and `SELECT pg_relpages('fruittable');`

Comment: Ok. So first output is:

    pg_stat_get_live_tuples: 0
    pg_stat_get_dead_tuples: 0
    pg_relation_size: 29539123200
    pg_total_relation_size: 32118743040


and second output is:

    avg: 1354.68

Comment: @SørenKnudsen 0 live and 0 dead rows?  The least I can say that it is strange...

Comment: Can you show us the table definition (columns, datatypes, indexes, constraints)?

Answer (score 3):

"Seq scans" means full table scan.  It's always going to read all of the columns on your table.  It's a full table scan.  PostgreSQL uses row-based storage, so it can't just read one column at a time.

The reason your query takes so long is that you're reading 7.2 million rows in the table and aggregating them.  Apparently, on a fairly slow computer.